# Firebird autoincrement column

Tags: triggers, generator, firebird

I need help creating an auto-increment column in Firebird.

Here is my table below

I want column *Seqid* to be auto incrementing

```
create Table TS_PRODUCT_PRICEHISTORY
(
  Seqid int not null,
  Remarks varchar(100)
)
```

I created a generator

```
CREATE GENERATOR tsproductpricehistory_gen_id;
```

Then create a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER aitspph_id FOR TS_PRODUCT_PRICEHISTORY
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
IF (NEW.SEQID IS NULL) THEN
NEW.SEQID = GEN_ID(tsproductpricehistory_gen_id,1);
END
```

When I try to create a trigger via above code I get this error

> Error: *** IBPP::SQLException *** Context: Statement::Prepare( CREATE
> TRIGGER aitspph_id FOR TS_PRODUCT_PRICEHISTORY ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT
> POSITION 0 AS BEGIN IF (NEW.SEQID IS NULL) THEN NEW.SEQID =
> GEN_ID(tsproductpricehistory_gen_id,1) ) Message: isc_dsql_prepare
> failed
>
> SQL Message : -104 Invalid token
>
> Engine Code    : 335544569 Engine Message : Dynamic SQL Error SQL
> error code = -104 Unexpected end of command - line 6, column 50

I can't seem to find whats wrong with the code creating the trigger.

Comment: Did you try changing the terminator?  SET TERM ^^ ; before your create trigger statement.  [Example in the Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq78/)

Comment: How (what tool) are you executing this DDL?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
CREATE TABLE TS_PRODUCT_PRICEHISTORY (
  SEQID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  REMARKS  VARCHAR(100)
);

/* Autoincrement for field (SEQID) */
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_TS_PRODUCT_PRICEHISTORY_ID;

SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER TS_PRODUCT_PRICEHISTORY_BI FOR TS_PRODUCT_PRICEHISTORY
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.SEQID IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.SEQID = GEN_ID(GEN_TS_PRODUCT_PRICEHISTORY_ID,1);
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: Why should the OP and researchers "Try this one"?  A good answer always includes some explanation of what it is doing and why it is advisable.  Code-only answers are low-value.  Please make your answer educational.